SharePoint Online content Approval and MS Teams Approval center not sync
I've set up a document library with content approval enabled and created a Power Automate "First to respond" flow for approvals, with notifications sent to MS Teams. Everything's running smoothly, except for one issue: the approval status in SharePoint isn't syncing with the status in the MS Teams approval center.
This means that when an approval is made or rejected through the SharePoint library, the status remains as "Requested" in the Teams approval center and doesn't get updated. As a result, the approvers aren't notified that the item has been approved or rejected. However, it works the other way around if an item is approved or rejected from the Teams approval center.
How can we synchronize these two environments to allow approvers to approve items from both SharePoint and Teams, ensuring that the status is updated in both environments?

To synchronize the approval status between SharePoint Online and the Microsoft Teams Approval Center, you can create a flow that triggers when an approval status changes in either SharePoint or Teams, you can update the status in the other environment accordingly.

Trigger: Use the "When an item is created or modified" trigger in Power Automate for SharePoint to detect changes in the approval status.
Actions: Update the corresponding approval status in the Microsoft Teams Approval Center using the "Update an approval" action in Power Automate.
Conditions: Use conditional statements to ensure that the status is updated bidirectionally between SharePoint and Teams.

Thanks for your response. I couldn't find "Update an approval" action in Power Automate, could you please share a screenshot of the exact name of that action?

Apologies, we checked this and observed that this action is not available within Power Automate. There doesn't seem to be any action available which will change approval status in Microsoft Teams Approval according to the status from SharePoint. However, vice-a-versa is feasible.

You need a 'Start and wait for approval' action, than a 'Switch'. See attached picture.

